# reading from pipe for SPI

Tags: c, linux, spi

I'm working with a ulinux on a microblaze.

Ive some Problem with SPI. 
My code works i see that the pipe is read out. But how can i check the data (rdata) printf doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
//slavetool

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    uint8_t rdata[1500];
    int ctrl = 0;
    int fd;
    int pipenr = 9;
    int n;
    char device[15];
    fd_set socks;

    //open codec
    sprintf(device,"/dev/spi/pipe%d", pipenr);
    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if(fd < 0)
        {
        printf("Failed to open pipe %s\n", device);
        return 0;
        } else 
        {
        printf("openend %s\n", device);
        }   
    printf("fd = %i\n", fd);

    printf("Initialisation complete!\n");


while(1)
    {
        printf("try to set!\n");

        FD_ZERO(&socks);
        FD_SET(fd, &socks);

        printf("fd_set set!\n");

        n = select(fd + 1, &socks, NULL, NULL, NULL);   

        //printf("Select is %i!\n", n);

        if(FD_ISSET(fd, &socks)) 
        {
           ctrl = read(fd, &rdata, 1500);
           printf("entered data: %s", rdata);  //DOESN'T WORK
           printf("ctrl: %i", ctrl);           //DOESN'T WORK
           printf("Check1\n");                 // WORK

                if(ctrl<0) 
                {
                    perror("read");
                    printf("Ende ctrl ist %i!\n",ctrl);
                    FD_ZERO(&socks);
                    close(fd);
                    return -1;
                }  

                printf("Check2\n"); 



        } else {printf("FD_ISSET not set");}


    }

    close(fd);


    return 0;
}
```

Terminal:

```
# ./spiread
openend /dev/spi/pipe9
fd = 3
Initialisation complete!
try to set!
fd_set set!
Select is 1!
Wait:
Check1
Check2
```

*Edit Thanks for you rapid answer. Don't work! Jumping over that print().
**Edit Oh it works!  Thx Alter Mann. Cant vote up -.-

Comment: Take a look to the edit of my answer, it was not correct

Answer (score 2):

```
uint8_t rdata[1500];
...
ctrl = read(fd, &rdata, 1500);
printf("entered data: %s", rdata);  //DOESN'T WORK
```

I suggest to change this to:

```
char rdata[1500];
...
ctrl = read(fd, rdata, sizeof(rdata) - 1);
if (ctrl == -1) {
  perror("read");
  exit(EXIT_FALURE);
}
rdata[ctrl] = '\0'; // read() doesn't add a trailing 0
printf("entered data: %s", rdata);
```

Note that [recv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) is prefered to `read` on modern systems

Comment: @AlterMann: you have a buffer overflow in your code. It should be "ctrl = read(fd, rdata, sizeof(rdata) - 1);". If you read a full 1500 bytes, the null byte will be outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @DoxyLover, I think you're wrong: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/read.html, take a look to the example at the end.

Comment: @AlterMann: the difference is that in that example, they are not writing the extra null byte. In your code, the read() may read 1500 bytes (sizeof(rdata)) filling the buffer. In this case, your last assignment will write to rdata[1500] which overflows the array. I stand by my comment!

Comment: @DoxyLover, ops, you are right, now I see my mistake, thanks for correction.

Comment: Yeah there is a stack overflow. Thx again!^^